# Dynamically set image or html as Background in Angular 4 Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular 4. I am trying to set dynamically a background in my component. In my case a background might be a Image file or a Html file.

I managed to do it with the image, but I have problems with the Html part.

I would appreciate some help here: 
First I want to check if my file is html like so: `if(background.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() === 'html')`

if true then set isHtml to true and with the help of http.get() read the content of the html file and that is what I want to give [innerHtml].

Although it seems easy I can't manage to do it right. Thanks for the help.

**HomeBackgroundComponent.ts**

```
export class HomeBackgroundComponent {
public backgroundPath$: Observable<string>;
public isHtml = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

constructor(public viewContext: ViewContextService, private vlmService: VlmService, private httpService: Http) {
    viewContext.title = 'Home';
    viewContext.id = 'HomeBackgroundComponent';

    this.backgroundPath$ = vlmService.background$.map(background => {
        return '../../../assets/background/' + background;
    });
}
}
```

**HomeBackgroundComponent.html**:

```
<div>
    <img *ngIf="!(isHtml | async)" [src]="backgroundPath$ | async" />
    <div *ngIf="(isHtml | async)" [innerHTML]="(backgroundPath$ | async)"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Update**: I am now a bit closer to what I want to accomplish, the only thing missing reading the html file with httpService.get()

```
vlmService.background$.subscribe(background => {
        if (background.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() === 'html') {
            this.isHtml.next(true);

            this.backgroundPath$ = vlmService.background$.map(bkg => {
                // TODO: here should be this.httpService.get(the html file)
                return '<h1>HELLO DEVID</h1>';
            });

        } else {
            this.isHtml.next(false);

            this.backgroundPath$ = vlmService.background$.map(bkg => {
                return '../../../assets/background/' + bkg;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: The first issue would be: read a html file for example test.html with http.get() and store it in the backGroundPath$ variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is finally the solution:

```
export class HomeBackgroundComponent {
public backgroundPath$: Observable<string>;
public isHtml$ = new Observable<boolean>();
public htmlFile$ = new Observable<string>();

constructor(public viewContext: ViewContextService, private vlmService: VlmService, private http: Http) {
    viewContext.title = 'Home';
    viewContext.id = 'HomeBackgroundComponent';

    this.backgroundPath$ = vlmService.background$.map(background => {
        return '../../../assets/customize/' + background;
    });

    this.isHtml$ = this.backgroundPath$.map(path => path.endsWith('.html'));

    this.htmlFile$ = this.backgroundPath$
        .filter(path => path.endsWith('.html'))
        .switchMap(path => {
            return this.http.get(path).map(response => response.text());
        });
}
}
```